# Synchronization method vs private final object for locking in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Can anyone tell me which one is better approach between synchronization method and private final object in java and why ??

```
public class kclass {

    private final Object myObject = new Object();

    public synchronized void show() {
       ...
    } 

    public void show1() {
        synchronized(myObject) {
            ...
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: ??? `synchronized` and `private` do *completely* different things. What actual problem are you trying to solve? Could you please [edit] your question with more background?

Comment: Recommended reading: **[Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/31260)**. "If your question... is just a copy paste of homework problem, expect it to be downvoted, closed, and deleted - potentially in quite short order."

Comment: @amon: the distinction is between `synchronized method() { ... }` and `method() { synchronize (obj) { ... } }` with a `private final Object obj;`

Answer (score 3):

In general both approaches are legit.
Using a dedicated object to `synchronize` on allows you to do more fine-grained synchronization than using `synchronized` on the method level: you may synchronize only part of a method or use different lock objects for different synchronization purposes.
`synchronized` (non static) methods will implicitly synchronize on the object they are called on, so their whole body is synchronized.